# Displaying an animated PNG in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, animation

I was wondering if there is a library or code snippet available for .NET (or that I can translate to .NET) to display animated PNG files (on the Graphics object, or even in a custom control)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some googling finds this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/APNGViewer.aspx

Its written in C#, which you shouldn't find too difficult to translate in VB.NET =)

Comment: If you have any problems translating the code, you can always compile it into a DLL and add the DLL as a reference in your project too =)

Comment: That's what I did, it's just the simplest way :) I will rewrite the library in a cleaner way sometime, though.